# Javascript - Second Drop-down Menu Disappears After Selection?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple drop down menus that correlate with each other. The first selection reveals a second menu (one of two), which in turn reveals content (Menu-ception!). However, when you finish this process the second menu disappears, I would like it to remain open for easy access.

I want to stick with plain Javascript for the moment, no JQuery solutions please.

I am new to coding so go easy haha. Any help is appreciated, Cheers!

```js
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('change', function() {
  'use strict';
  var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),
    target = document.getElementById(this.value);
  if (vis !== null) {
    vis.className = 'inv';
  }
  if (target !== null) {
    target.className = 'vis';
  }
});

document.getElementById('trad').addEventListener('change', function() {
  'use strict';
  var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),
    target = document.getElementById(this.value);
  if (vis !== null) {
    vis.className = 'inv';
  }
  if (target !== null) {
    target.className = 'vis';
  }
});

document.getElementById('simp').addEventListener('change', function() {
  'use strict';
  var vis = document.querySelector('.vis'),
    target = document.getElementById(this.value);
  if (vis !== null) {
    vis.className = 'inv';
  }
  if (target !== null) {
    target.className = 'vis';
  }
});
```

```css
    p {
      font-size: 2.5vw;
      font-family: arial;
    }
    select {
      width: auto;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 2.5vw;
      font-family: arial;
    }
    .inv {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<select id="target">
  <option value="">System</option>
  <option value="trad">Traditional</option>
  <option value="simp">Simplfit</option>

  <select>

    <select id="trad" class="inv">
      <option value="">Width</option>
      <option value="content1">400</option>
      <option value="content2">600</option>
      <option value="content3">800</option>
      <option value="content4">1000</option>
      <option value="content5">1210</option>
      <select>

        <select id="simp" class="inv">
          <option value="">Width</option>
          <option value="content6">400</option>
          <option value="content7">600</option>
          <option value="content8">800</option>
          <option value="content9">1000</option>
          <option value="content10">1210</option>
          <select>

            <p id="content1" class="inv">Content 1</p>

            <p id="content2" class="inv">Content 2</p>

            <p id="content3" class="inv">Content 3</p>

            <p id="content4" class="inv">Content 4</p>

            <p id="content5" class="inv">Content 5</p>

            <p id="content6" class="inv">Content 6</p>

            <p id="content7" class="inv">Content 7</p>

            <p id="content8" class="inv">Content 8</p>

            <p id="content9" class="inv">Content 9</p>

            <p id="content10" class="inv">Content 10</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way you are fetching the visible element for `trad` and `simp` handlers.

Since you were fetching the `.vis` element with `queryselector` it will return the current select element because that is having the `vis` class instead of one of the `content<\d>` element, just fine tuning that selector should fix the problem.

```js
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('change', function() {
  'use strict';
  var vis = document.querySelector('select.vis'),
    target = document.getElementById(this.value),
    ct = document.querySelector('.content.vis');
  if (vis !== null) {
    vis.className = 'inv';
  }
  if (target !== null) {
    target.className = 'vis';
  }
  if (ct != null) {
    ct.className = 'content inv';
  }
});

document.getElementById('trad').addEventListener('change', function() {
  'use strict';
  var vis = document.querySelector('.vis:not(select)'),
    target = document.getElementById(this.value);
  if (vis !== null) {
    vis.className = 'content inv';
  }
  if (target !== null) {
    target.className = 'content vis';
  }
});

document.getElementById('simp').addEventListener('change', function() {
  'use strict';
  var vis = document.querySelector('.vis:not(select)'),
    target = document.getElementById(this.value);
  if (vis !== null) {
    vis.className = 'content inv';
  }
  if (target !== null) {
    target.className = 'content vis';
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  font-family: arial;
}
select {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  font-family: arial;
}
.inv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="target">
  <option value="">System</option>
  <option value="trad">Traditional</option>
  <option value="simp">Simplfit</option>
  <!--Need closing tag here-->
</select>

<select id="trad" class="inv">
  <option value="">Width</option>
  <option value="content1">400</option>
  <option value="content2">600</option>
  <option value="content3">800</option>
  <option value="content4">1000</option>
  <option value="content5">1210</option>
  <!--Need closing tag here-->
</select>

<select id="simp" class="inv">
  <option value="">Width</option>
  <option value="content6">400</option>
  <option value="content7">600</option>
  <option value="content8">800</option>
  <option value="content9">1000</option>
  <option value="content10">1210</option>
  <!--Need closing tag here-->
</select>

<p id="content1" class="content inv">Content 1</p>
<p id="content2" class="content inv">Content 2</p>
<p id="content3" class="content inv">Content 3</p>
<p id="content4" class="content inv">Content 4</p>
<p id="content5" class="content inv">Content 5</p>
<p id="content6" class="content inv">Content 6</p>
<p id="content7" class="content inv">Content 7</p>
<p id="content8" class="content inv">Content 8</p>
<p id="content9" class="content inv">Content 9</p>
<p id="content10" class="content inv">Content 10</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('change', function() {
  'use strict';
  var vis = document.querySelector('select.vis'),
    target = document.getElementById(this.value),
    ct = document.querySelector('.content.vis');
  if (vis !== null) {
    vis.className = 'inv';
  }
  if (target !== null) {
    target.className = 'vis';
  }
  if (ct != null) {
    ct.className = 'content inv';
  }
});

document.getElementById('trad').addEventListener('change', function() {
  'use strict';
  var vis = document.querySelector('.vis:not(select)'),
    target = document.getElementById(this.value);
  if (vis !== null) {
    vis.className = 'content inv';
  }
  if (target !== null) {
    target.className = 'content vis';
  }
});

document.getElementById('simp').addEventListener('change', function() {
  'use strict';
  var vis = document.querySelector('.vis:not(select)'),
    target = document.getElementById(this.value);
  if (vis !== null) {
    vis.className = 'content inv';
  }
  if (target !== null) {
    target.className = 'content vis';
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  font-family: arial;
}
select {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  font-family: arial;
}
.inv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="target">
  <option value="">System</option>
  <option value="trad">Traditional</option>
  <option value="simp">Simplfit</option>
  <!--Need closing tag here-->
</select>

<select id="trad" class="inv">
  <option value="">Width</option>
  <option value="content1">400</option>
  <option value="content2">600</option>
  <option value="content3">800</option>
  <option value="content4">1000</option>
  <option value="content5">1210</option>
  <!--Need closing tag here-->
</select>

<select id="simp" class="inv">
  <option value="">Width</option>
  <option value="content6">400</option>
  <option value="content7">600</option>
  <option value="content8">800</option>
  <option value="content9">1000</option>
  <option value="content10">1210</option>
  <!--Need closing tag here-->
</select>

<p id="content1" class="content inv">Content 1</p>
<p id="content2" class="content inv">Content 2</p>
<p id="content3" class="content inv">Content 3</p>
<p id="content4" class="content inv">Content 4</p>
<p id="content5" class="content inv">Content 5</p>
<p id="content6" class="content inv">Content 6</p>
<p id="content7" class="content inv">Content 7</p>
<p id="content8" class="content inv">Content 8</p>
<p id="content9" class="content inv">Content 9</p>
<p id="content10" class="content inv">Content 10</p>
```

Comment: You should add explanation to your answer.